# What do targeting beacons do on Star Wars Squadrons?

Tags: star-wars-squadrons

I couldn't find this anywhere.  What does the targeting beacon target, and what does it do?  How do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read this on reddit, and it says that Targeting Beacons add around 30% more damage to marked enemies. However, it does NOT remove the Targeting Jammer effect.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the reddit article?